# foundation-apps error without angular

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

Is angular required to use foundation-apps? I don't want to use angular, but get an error in foundation-apps.js when i run without it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as Twitter Bootstrap's Js components were built using the jQuery framework, Foundation for apps team did choose the angularJs framework to build their Js components. without it none of those should work :

```
 - Panels
 - Action-Sheet
 - Off-canvas Menu
 - Modal
 - Notification
 - Accordion
 - Interchange
 - Popup
 - Tabs
 - templates caching
 - the built-in routing
 - ...
```

If you don't want to use angular I would recommand using [Foundation for Sites 6](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html) instead as it uses jQuery, flex box, basically similar naming classes, grids and similar or even more components.